# MongoDB conditional if else if with exists

Tags: mongodb

I am stuck in a query,
my case is

```
if user id exists then user id
else if user name exists then user name
else if user email exists then user email
else ''
```

Here, is my code.

```
$project: {
    ..... other fields,
    'userDetail': {
        $cond: {
            if: {
                $exists: ['$user.id']
            },
            then: '$user.id',
            else: {
                $cond: {
                    if: {
                        $exists: ['$user.name']
                    },
                    then: '$user.name',
                    else: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: {
                                $exists: ['$user.email']
                            },
                            then: '$user.email',
                            else: '',
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since, $exists don't work on this. Can anybody, help me finding the solution to this problem?
Also, if user.id is '' (empty string) & user.name is "Marcus". I want the result to return user.name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query

- if `id` is false or empty string, try the `name`, else if `name` false or empty string, try the `email`, else `""`
- false are all not-exists/null/false
- the types of those fields are not booleans, so you are safe to use this way

*in case you really needed the `$exist` for example you wanted to keep the `null` or the `false` values, you could use this `{"$eq":[{"$type":"$user.id"}, "missing"]}`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=71206240-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"userInfo":
   {"$switch":
    {"branches":
     [{"case":{"$and":["$user.id", {"$ne":["$user.id", ""]}]},
       "then":"$user.id"},
      {"case":{"$and":["$user.name", {"$ne":["$user.name", ""]}]},
       "then":"$user.name"},
      {"case":{"$and":["$user.email", {"$ne":["$user.email", ""]}]},
       "then":"$user.email"}],
     "default":""}}}}])
```

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood correctly (and based on your example) you can use a query like this:

The trick here is to use [ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) instead of `$exists`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "userDetail": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$ifNull": [
              "$user.id",
              false
            ]
          },
          // user id exists
          "$user.id",
          // user id no exists
          {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$ifNull": [
                  "$user.name",
                  false
                ]
              },
              // user name exists
              "$user.name",
              // user name no exists
              {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$ifNull": [
                      "$user.email",
                      false
                    ]
                  },
                  // user email exists
                  "$user.email",
                  // user email no exists
                  ""
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7szob1lAb2r)

Comment: If a case arise, where my user.id = '' (empty string) & user.name = "Marcus". The result is returning user.id. I want to handle this situation too, like if user.id is '', then user.name should be returned as result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested `$ifNull` operator, by checking nested condition,

```
  {
    $project: {
      userDetail: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$user.id",
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$user.name",
              { $ifNull: ["$user.email", ""] }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0G2ijlICGu5)

Answer (score 0):

nested if else

```
tasks: {
          $addToSet: {
            $cond: {
              if: {
                $eq: [
                  {
                    $ifNull: ['$tasks.id', ''],
                  },
                  '',
                ],
              },
              then: '$$REMOVE',
              else: {
                id: '$tasks.id',
                description: '$tasks.description',
                assignee: {
                  $cond: {
                    if: {
                      $eq: [
                        {
                          $ifNull: ['$tasks.assignee._id', ''],
                        },
                        '',
                      ],
                    },
                    then: undefined,
                    else: {
                      id: '$tasks.assignee._id',
                      name: '$tasks.assignee.name',
                      thumbnail: '$tasks.assignee.thumbnail',
                      status: '$tasks.assignee.status',
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        }
```